# Recover files from a reformatted drive

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, filesystem-corruption

My friend has an HP laptop that recently stopped working.  It was trying to run chkdsk but it kept on freezing up, and safe mode would not work.

So he reformatted the drive and re-installed Windows 32 bit (this is a 64 bit system) but it has no drivers at all.

So he wanted to recover some files. He scanned with Recuva to hopefully get back most of his files.

When he does get them back is there any possible way for him to make a HP recovery CD from those files? He forgot to make one. Is there any way that maybe the files for that CD will be recovered?

Answer (score 1):

> "So he reformatted the drive and re-installed Windows 32 bit."

He shouldn't have formatted the drive then reinstalled Windows on it *before* attempting to recover his data. Now some of that data has been overwritten with new data and will no longer be recoverable. He should have put the drive inside another PC as a secondary drive for the restore (or used a USB -> SATA adapter to attach it to another system).

Unfortunately- he can't make a recovery CD from files recovered by Recuva. If the entire drive was formatted first, then you can say goodbye to that option.

I think recovery discs are very overrated though- better to take an image of your PC and restore to that if something goes wrong. That way your PC is in a more customized and useful state (applications and updates installed etc.) than the default factory state you are left with after using recovery discs.